# Python Ping Servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ping

First time poster, long time reader.
I'm hoping someone might be able to provide some insight into a python script that utilizes concurrent.futures (or some other concurrency method) for pinging a list of IPs. A lot of the solutions I've seen utilize IP ranges between 1-100 (but using the same first two to three octets ie 192.168.1.x) but are not inserting a list of real world IPs; that means I can't use those as I can't account for every single IP range as that's just excessive overhead.

I've had a bash at creating my own but I don't know if it actually is running concurrently (not very adept with Python) so any insight on either checking or making more efficient would be greatly appreciated. In a perfect world, I'd like to retain the ability to change how many pings the script sends.

```
###Ping List of Addresses###
start = time.perf_counter()

def ping_function(host):
    parameter = '-n' if platform.system().lower()=='windows' else '-c'

    command = ['ping', parameter, '1', host]
    return subprocess.call(command)==0

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = executor.map(ping_function, IP)

print(tuple(result))

finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Pinging completed in {round(finish-start)} second(s)')
```

Any insight that could be provided would be absolutely unreal and would be hugely beneficial. The above code excerpt has the list inserted as "IP". The above code runs currently in 2 seconds but the list is quite short at 25 entries for a proof of concept. The list's datasource is from Sharepoint so the more items that are added, the larger the list will become and the longer the script will take to run.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's the question here? What problem are you having with the code?

Comment: You here are assuming that the Windows `ping` command returns a different status for success and failure.  That is not the case.  You're going to need to read the stdout and parse it.

Comment: @Barmar there isn't a real 'problem' so to speak but more of a question as to whether the code is running concurrently or not. I'm not adept enough to check whether it is or isn't...I don't think it is however. - mainly because of how quickly concurrent code works. Whenever I increase the 'pings sent' the code heavily increases. When I was running it without concurrency, so just a standard ping command, it was about 2 seconds too (hence how I arrived at it wasn't working)

Comment: @TimRoberts how would I work that different status for success/failure in? Cheers

Comment: You could add `time.sleep(1)` to your ping function, that should make it obvious if things run in parallel.

Comment: @JanWilamowski I added the time.sleep(1) under "command = [XXX]" and also found this statement on google: print(f'process {os.getpid()}')

When combined, they're reporting that they're all the same PID and the code function has increased a second (which I think is attributed to the time.sleep(1) though)

Comment: If the overall runtime increases by 25 seconds, there is no parallelization. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: I'm seeing the same PID and the thing increasing in duration by about 5 seconds when adding the time.sleep function.

Comment: @mgeale -- What status do you care about?  Isn't this a boolean operation?  Either you can reach them, or you can't.

Comment: @TimRoberts I only care about whether the servers in the list are pingable - whether a boolean or some other method can achieve that or return that information, I'm all ears.

Comment: How many CPUs are you running this with? If Python only detects a single CPU, the thread executor will start 5 threads by default, thus reducing the runtime increase to 5s instead of 25s.

Comment: @mgeale -- You'll have to capture the output and search for the appropriate strings.

Comment: @JanWilamowski currently just running on a laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T470s) for a proof of concept but will eventually be moved to a server running in a VM where basically sky is the limit.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you provide an example on how exactly I could do that or the above code with it incorporated? Still unsure on how to get the concurrency working. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`ping` on Windows does not set the exit code, so you can't use that to determine success.  Instead, you have to look for clues in the output.  A successful ping outputs 'TTL' to indicate the time-to-live value.  This works for me.  I capture the output of the command, and use the presence of the string 'TTL' to indicate success.  It checks these 6 systems in 3 seconds:

```
import time
import subprocess
import concurrent.futures
from sys import platform

IP = [
    '192.168.192.10',
    '192.168.192.11',
    '192.168.192.12',
    '192.168.192.13',
    '192.168.192.14',
    '192.168.192.15'
]
start = time.perf_counter()

def ping_function(host):
    parameter = '-n' if platform=='win32' else '-c'
    command = ['ping', parameter, '1', host]
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(command)
        return b'TTL' in output
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = executor.map(ping_function, IP)

print(tuple(result))

finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Pinging completed in {round(finish-start)} second(s)')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works an absolute treat now!

Just out of interest, is there anyway to include/account for error handling? When someone adds the servers to the Sharepoint list (automated via PowerApps and PowerAutomate Flow), they won't have an IP until someone manually adds it so the cell value that the above IP list is coming from won't have a value causing the above code / ping to fail...how would I account for that? In the IP [] list creation, I have something along the lines of If Cell empty, set None in the list...so it falls over. 
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: It's easy enough to add `if not host:` / `return False` to the start of the function.  Or, filter the list by `IP = [i for i in IP if i]`.

Comment: You're a legend! Thanks a bunch for your help. Thanks for being patient and walking me through it :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pest and ping you again, but since adding the error handling for the empty cells, I've intentionally added a down IP into the datasource to try and simulate an outage. Its now failing on the entire thing (ie exit code 1). Are you able to just have another squiz at the above and suggest anything? Cheers :)

Comment: "Failing" how?  Error?  Show us the traceback.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. There are more, but they're all subprocess.check_output(command) exceptions, get results etc.

File "C:\...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ping', '-n', '1', '10.101.41.218']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The IP in question is one that is intentionally down. The desired result of the script is that if the IP is down, the script just puts 'Offline' in the output...managed to get that with the Online one(s).

Comment: That's interesting, but that's easy to handle.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Saw that you fixed it - I had a feeling it was something like that but when I was writing it up, I wasn't putting it in the right place. Thought I should check to see if it was something else that I was missing. Works a treat now. Thanks a bunch. Will mark as answered.